# Conditional routing in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to only be able to load a component if the user is authenticated to. Normally I have this `PrivateRoute` component for that:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, hasAccess, addUser, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      hasAccess === true ? <Component {...props} addUser={addUser} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
    }
  />
);
```

Which I call like this:

```
   <PrivateRoute
      hasAccess={hasAccess}
      path="/settings"
      component={Setting}
    />
```

But in the other case I can't reuse this code. So I decided to just declare the route like this:

```
<Route
  createMeeting={createMeeting}
  path="/meetings"
  component={MeetingRoutes}
  render={props =>
    createMeeting === true ? <Component {...props} createMeeting={createMeeting} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
  } />
```

It should act the same as the PrivateRoute if you ask me, but it doesn't. Instead I got this error message:

> Warning: You should not use `<Route component>` and `<Route render>` in
>   the same route; `<Route render>` will be ignored

Can someone explain to me why it gives me this error? I can't find the solution for my problem.

Comment: what is the issue in doing first approach?

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-redirects-auth-668he. Why are you using both components and render together ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will better to write a reusable `PrivateRoute`:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, hasAccess, componentProps = {}, redirectTo = "/", ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            hasAccess ? <Component {...props} {...componentProps} /> : <Redirect to={redirectTo} />
        }
    />
);
```

So with `Settings` you could use this route like this:

```
<PrivateRoute
    hasAccess={hasAccess}
    path="/settings"
    component={Setting}
    componentProps={{
        addUser: addUser
    }}
/>
```

and with `MeetingRoutes` like this:

```
<PrivateRoute
    hasAccess={hasAccessToMeetingRoutes}
    path="/meetings"
    component={MeetingRoutes}
    componentProps={{
        createMeeting: createMeeting
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your route in ternary operator and add one Redirect component at the end of routes.

Comment: Well the problem is, this route redirects to another route file. In this file only certain routes can be accessed and the rest should be accessible based on the `createMeeting` boolean. I want to pass this prop to that file and use the ternary there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to wrap component of route need authenticated other components no need authenticated you can render them normally

Example HOC authentication:

```
const loginGuard = Component =>
  connect(state => ({
    auth: getAuth(state),
  }))(({ auth, ...props }) => {
    if (auth) {
      return <Component auth={auth} {...props} />;
    }

    // push to sign in if try access to component requires authentication
    history.push('/sign-in');
    return null;
  });
```

Usage:

```
<Route
    {...rest}
    component={loginGuard(AdminComponent)}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the component property in your new Route, like this:

```
const DynamicComp = MeetingRoutes

 return <Route 
  createMeeting={createMeeting}
  path="/meetings"
  render={props =>
    createMeeting === true ? <DynamicComp {...props} createMeeting={createMeeting} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
  } />
```

Comment: But how does it know which component it should render now?

Comment: The component can be dynamic, and you can declare it outside this JSX.
dynamicComp = MeetingRoutes